# Как превратить программу написанную на python 3.2 в исполняемый файл linux?

Tags: linux, python-3.x

Как скомпилировать .py файлы в исполняемый файл Linux со всеми его зависимостями?
Собирать все и компилировать могу под Windows но работать приложение должно под Linux

Comment: Вообще-то, **исполняемый файл Linux** это файл, для которого взведены биты "Исполнимый" в структуре *dirent* и в первой его строке прописано: "#!/usr/bin/python". И компилировать не обязательно.  Наверное, Вы имели в виду **двоичный** исполнимый ?

Comment: контекста бы добавить в вопрос, пока о пустом спросил автор.

Answer (score 0):

**Pyinstaller по моему позволяет собирать приложения под Linux на Windows но сами они рекомендуют собирать под Linux на Linux'е**